# Sending an Image from HTML canvas to C# Server

Tags: javascript, c#, html, canvas, websocket

Currently I have this code on my c# server which receives the image:

```
BitmapSource bmp = Method.BitmapFromBase64(data.Substring(22));

public static BitmapSource BitmapFromBase64(string b64string)
{
    var bytes = Convert.FromBase64String(b64string);

    using (var stream = new MemoryStream(bytes))
    {
        return BitmapFrame.Create(stream,
            BitmapCreateOptions.None, BitmapCacheOption.OnLoad);
    }
}
```

My server recieves the image that was created using the `Canvas.toDataURL()` method in JavaScript.  Now for whatever reason this code throws an exception about having an invalid Base64 character.

Now my actual question is: How can I make this code work, or what is a good alternative?

**EDIT**

I've just narrowed this issue down hugely.  It has to do with the server receiving a string that isn't the same as the original Base64.  It contains a bunch of garbage characters

Comment: the data URI **includes** the base 64. You need to parse it to remove the parts that aren't using that method. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLCanvasElement/toDataURL

Comment: @charliefl Yes, that's why I'm using the `Substring(22)`, but thanks for the reply

Comment: have you verified in browser that it is Substring(22)? Seems to me parsing in browser would make more sense

Comment: `Substring(0, 25)` returns "data:image/png;base64,iVB", so `Substring(22)` works

Comment: Just tried parsing it in the browser, and got the same result anyways